# How to delete rows in SQLite with multiple where args?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want to delete rows which satisfy any of multiple conditions.

For example, I pass a list of IDs, and I want to delete all rows with these `IDs` (IDs are unique).

This would be:

```
String[] ids = {"0", "1", "2", "3",...};
database.delete("rows" , "id=? OR id=? OR id=? OR id=? OR ..." , ids );
```

Is there any way to do it compact without multiple `OR`?

Comment: SQL, you can use DISTINCT.

Comment: use DELETE FROM your_table_name WHERE ID IN (ids[0], ids[1],...)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You may get it done through `db.execSQL` method and SQL's **IN** keyword. For example:

```
String args = TextUtils.join(", ", ids);

db.execSQL(String.format("DELETE FROM rows WHERE ids IN (%s);", args));
```

Comment: One way to do it is: for(int i = 0; i < ids.sixe(); ++i) { database.delete("rows", "id=" + ids.get(i), null); } I want to know if I can do that but in compact formar, with only one sentence "delete"

Comment: you can do that too but in that case it will execute sql statements a couple of times and has performance impact. Instead, I would suggest you to use **IN** statement to execute your query in bulk.

Comment: This is nice and short but it's not using parameter binding, which is a security concern. What if there happens to be an id like `1) OR (1=1` ...

Comment: TextUtil.join didn't know about it before ! pretty handy

Comment: Pēteris Caune, I believe you are correct. The command should be `... WHERE ids IN (?)` and then args should be passed as the second argument to `execSQL()`

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson's solution is safer, which prevent SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 18):

What you want to use is an `IN` clause, something like (with 4 IDs);

```
database.delete("rows", "id IN (?, ?, ?, ?)", ids );
```

Upon request, this is (one example of) how you can do it dynamically;

```
database.delete("rows", 
    "id IN (" + new String(new char[ids.length-1]).replace("\0", "?,") + "?)", 
    ids);
```

Comment: But the problem is that I have multiple IDs in the "ids" array, maybe 4 or maybe 1000 IDs.

Comment: One way to do it is:

for(int i = 0; i < ids.sixe(); ++i) {
     database.delete("rows", "id=" + ids.get(i), null);
}

I want to know if I can do that but in compact formar, with only one sentence "delete".

Comment: @alberking Added a dynamic version.

Comment: @waqaslam Why do you say so? As, I just tested this code - https://gist.github.com/yccheok/ae18957e2715173adb50b426a1ef455d It works fine for me.

Answer (score 7):

Android official documentation tells [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String)) that using execSQL is not the proper way to delete records.

I would like to suggest the following simple method. Using provided `delete()` api.

```
String[] idArray = new String[] {"1", "2", "3"};
String idsCSV = TextUtils.join(",", idArray);
SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
if (db != null) {
    db.delete("table_name", "id IN (" + idsCSV + ")", null);
    db.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, ...)` and directly print your array values inside the brackets:

```
database.delete("rows", String.format("id IN (%s)", StringUtils.join(ids, ",")));
```

As an alternative, I'd try to use some kind of `flags` column for such things (if there's something like being able to flag single entries for deletion; I don't know how your ID list is "built").

Comment: One way to do it is: for(int i = 0; i < ids.sixe(); ++i) { database.delete("rows", "id=" + ids.get(i), null); } I want to know if I can do that but in compact formar, with only one sentence "delete"

Comment: If you're not working with an array, you could just use a loop like yours concatenating a string with all ids (essentially the same as the result from `StringUtils.join()`.

Comment: In order to satisfy the 3 args needed for `delete()`, you'll need to add `new String [] {}`.

Comment: Same as for waqaslam's answer, splicing parameters into SQL query is not a good practice. It is OK in some cases but generally should be avoided

Comment: @PēterisCaune Well, you have to assume they're safe already. Of course you shouldn't just throw in whatever you've got from a query.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example which builds the "?, ?, ?, ..." placeholder string with StringBuilder. If there are many parameters, plain string concatenation would create lots of garbage, StringBuilder helps with that.

```
String[] ids = {"0", "1", "2", "3",...};

StringBuilder placeholders = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    if (i != 0)
        placeholders.append(", ");

    placeholders.append("?");
}

String where = "id IN (" + placeholders.toString() + ")";

db.delete("rows", where, args);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using this :

**Sqlite Statement Syntax :**

```
db.delete(TABLE_NAME,"COLUMN IN (?)", new String[]{commaSaparatedString})
```

**Example based on question :**

```
String args = TextUtils.join(", ", ids);
db.delete("rows","id IN (?)", new String[]{args})
```

Comment: This did not work for me, `db.delete` returned `0` = no rows got deleted.

Comment: here is the reason why it doesn't work and how to do this right https://stackoverflow.com/a/26230484/4528239

Answer (score 0):

This work for my varchar ID.

```
public Integer deleteObjects(List<Object> objects){
    if (objects.size()<1) return 0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    StringBuilder strb= new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i<objects.size();i++){
        strb.append("'");
        strb.append(objects.get(i).getId().toString());
        strb.append("'");
        // last element without comma
        if (i<objects.size()-1) strb.append(","); 
    }
    int rows = db.delete("table_name","id IN (" + strb + ")",null);
    db.close();
    return rows;
}
```

This build WHERE string with args directly. Equivalent to:

```
 db.delete(TABLE_NAME,"id IN ('id0-maddog','id1-foo','id2-bar')",null);
```