# Delete multiple rows using IDs?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

How can I delete multiple rows by a list of IDs in Android SQLite database?

I have defined a general delete method in this manner:

```
protected void deleteWhere(String whereClause, String[] whereArgs) {
    try {
        databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase().delete(
                getTableName(), whereClause, whereArgs);
    } finally {
        databaseHelper.close();
    }
}
```

And now I'm trying to call it with a list of IDs:

```
public void deleteAll(Iterable<T> entities) {
    Iterable<Long> ids = Iterables.transform(entities, getId);

    String whereClause = getIdColumn() + " IN (?)";
    String[] whereArgs = { TextUtils.join(",", ids) };
    deleteWhere(whereClause, whereArgs);
}
```

If the ID list contains for example the values [1, 2, 42], then I assume the resulting SQL should be:

```
DELETE FROM tableName WHERE _id IN (1,2,42);
```

But this doesn't seem to work correctly. If the list contains only 1 ID, then it is correctly deleted. However, if I provide multiple values, than zero rows are affected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you give a single string as `whereArgs`, a single string ends up in the SQL command, as if you had written this:

```
... WHERE _id IN ('1,2,42')
```

This would compare each `_id` value against the value `'1,2,42'`, which of course does not work.

If you use three parameter markers and give three strings in the `whereArgs` array, you would end up with three strings, like this:

```
... WHERE _id in ('1','2','42')
```

This works only when the `_id` column has integer [affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity), which is true for a column declared as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, but not in the general case.

The Android database API does not allow query parameters to have any type but string.
When using integers, you should just insert them directly (as in [ianhanniballake's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26227289/delete-multiple-rows-using-ids/26227792#26227792)):

```java
String whereClause = getIdColumn() + " IN (" + TextUtils.join(",", ids) + ")";
```

Comment: Oh, now when I see the way the apostrophes are added to the values, it makes sense. However, isn't putting the values directly into `whereClause` prone to SQL injection? Wouldn't it be better to manually generate a `whereClause` with appropriate number of question marks and then pass the IDs into the `whereArgs` as String array?

Comment: Allowing only strings as parameters is a bug in the design of the Android database API. Anyway, integer values are safe against SQL injection; this problem occurs only with strings.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `whereArgs` for `IN` statements due to the escaping done by `whereArgs` (unless you make a separate `?` for each value) - instead, you have to embed the ids in your where statement:

```
String whereClause = getIdColumn() + " IN (" + TextUtils.join(",", ids) + ")";
deleteWhere(whereClause, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Each "?" will only bind to a single value. So if your id list has three values, your whereClause would need to be "_id IN (?,?,?)"

Comment: But I'm passing the IDs as one string consisting of the values joined by commas. That isn't permitted?

Comment: Good point - your whereArgs would also need to be an array of three values, not a single comma-separated string.