# sqlite3 delete multiple rows using "WHERE column IN (?)"

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to delete multiple rows with a single command:

```
String[] args = {"1143997,1144373,1144375,1144383,1144385,1144389"};
int n;
n = db.delete("mytable", "recno IN (?)", args);
Log.d(TAG, "Deleted " + n + " rows");
```

But it doesn't work. Neither did

```
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM mytable WHERE recno IN (?)", args);
```

But if I fetch the database file with `adb pull`, run sqlite3 from the command line, and type

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE recno in (1143997,1144373,1144375,1144383,1144385,1144389);
```

it works just fine. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `n` comma separated `?` for `n` arguments. Try something like:

```
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM mytable WHERE recno IN (?,?,?,...)", args);
```

You need one `?` per `argument` and `args` should be an array of arguments, not a string. It should be like

```
String args[] = {arg1, arg2, arg3, ...};
```

What you can do is programmatically create the `?` based on your number of arguments. Implement this function.

```
/**
 * Function to create the argument "?,?,?,.." string
 *
 * @param len The length of array of arguments
 */
String makePlaceholders(int len) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len * 2 - 1);
    sb.append("?");
    for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        sb.append(",?");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Then simply make your IN clause query as:

```
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM mytable WHERE recno IN (" + makePlaceholders(args.length()) + ")", args);
```

This should work well for your purpose. Hope this helps!

Comment: OK, that's a little trickier than I was counting on, because the number of arguments could vary, meaning I have to build my "?,?,?..." string programatically. Let me think about that...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your array is not well constructed.

You have this:

```
String[] args = {"1143997,1144373,1144375,1144383,1144385,1144389"};
```

But I think you want to do this:

```
String[] args = {"1143997","1144373","1144375","1144383","1144385","1144389"};
```

I think that your array contains only one element with all the IDs and you need an array with N elements, one per ID.

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14358049/3694355). It may help you.

Comment: That answer suggests using `String.format` to effectively generate `execSQL("DELETE FROM mytable WHERE recno IN (1143997,1144373,1144375,1144383,1144385,1144389)");` and no whereArgs argument to `execSQL()`. I try to avoid passing arguments without the whereArgs argument because of SQL injection attacks, but I guess in this case I'm pretty confident that this can't happen.